# Emulating a parabola in my game for a jump

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, conic-sections, quadratics

I am currently having some trouble understanding how to plot a parabola with the x and y coordinates.In my game a player needs to jump from point a to point b and the jump would look something like this:

[image]

Now I know that the equation of parabola is:
$y=ax^{2}+bx+c$

Now I am not sure what the values of $a$ and $b$ will be. What I currently am trying to do is achieve a corresponding value of $y$ for every $x$. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Update :
I am trying to implement @Demetri solution. 
Here is how I am doing it

```
        jumpXstart = CurrentXCordinate;
        jumpXend   = CurrentXCordinate + 120;
        jumpmidpoint = CurrentXCordinate + (120/2); //X cordinate for jump midpoint
        jumpheight = 60;
```

Then in the frame update I am doing this

```
        float x = CurrentXCordinate + 1; //This will continuously increment
        float temp =  (x - jumpXstart) * (x - jumpXend);
        float y = (-1 * jumpheight ) * temp;
        y = y / ( (jumpmidpoint - jumpXstart) * (jumpmidpoint - jumpXend));
```

Now on my first frame I get a negative value of y which is incorrect. 
Here are the values
x = 51
jumpXstart = 50
jumpXend = 170
jumpheight = 60 
jumpmidpoint = 110

The above values give a negative value of y . I believe the first value of y while taking off should be positive.

Comment: Can you describe what $x$ values the player jumps between? An easy parabola that does what you want from $x=a$ to $x=b$ is $y=-(x-a)(x-b)$

Comment: The player needs to jump from A to b where A is the initial value of x and and b is the final value of x (thats where the player should land)

Comment: The parabola in the previous comment will do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how long your jump should be, and the height of the jump, then the following will suffice:

$$ y= \dfrac{-\text{jump height}}{(M-\text{start})(M-\text{end})} (x-\text{start})(x-\text{end}) $$

Here, M is the midpoint between the jump start point and jump end point.

Comment: Just updated my post

Answer (score 0):

If your first point is $(x_0,0)$ and your second point is $(x_1,0)$ then your parabola will look like $y=a(x-x_0)(x-x_1)=ax^2-a(x_0+x_1)x+ax_0x_1$ where $a$ is arbitrary (negative) and then $b=-a(x_0+x_1)$ and $c=ax_0x_1$). How can $a$ still be arbitrary? Well, it depends not only on the gravitation but also on the time the whole jump takes - whihc you did not specify.

Comment: Say the jump needs to complete in 2 seconds. I can handle that through the velocity

Comment: So if I used the equation$y=a(x-x_0)(x-x_1)$ what value should I use for a ?